# In MaskedTextBox, how do I write a mask to check that the input is none empty?

Tags: c#, winforms

As far as I can tell, this is none regex.  And I can't find anywhere for quantifier.  This is what I have right now, which the MaskedTextBox does not recognize the + as a quantifier

```
A+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to validate the masked text box too early.  You can't know that it doesn't have any input until it doesn't have input.  I assume that you have some sort of form that you are having a user fill in and at the end they press a button to complete the data entry.  You can validate the input within that event.

If you just want to ensure non-empty then you can check the [`TextLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.textlength.aspx) field after focus leaves the textbox, or when a button is pushed, etc..

Comment: If that's the case then what is the point of the Masked Textbox in the first place?  I could have used events handling with normal Textbox.

Comment: Masked text boxes let you restrict to a very specific subset of inputs.  I have most often seen them used in telephone number input where the format is well known ahead of time `(XXX)XXX-XXXX` for example.  When use in a well defined way, you can use some [validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkx4h3az.aspx) to notify the user of the valid inputs.